# ODOO | Why do some FRENCH terms/strings remain untranslated?

Tags: odoo, translation, odoo-8, po

I've been using ODOO for a quite a while now, but i still do not get why some areas do not get translated, even though my .po file of French lang is fully translated:

Please view the images below

## notice that the pop up product.page shows untranslated strings, when compared to the full-screen product under WH/products.

[image]

[image]

[image]

PO FILE

[image]

## now we can see the same string translated in WH products.

[image]

ALSO I HAVE UNTRANSLATED strings in groups/messaging area .

[image]

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this?